# Router per pod and not depending on main router

Tags: javascript, ember.js

We just started using **EmberJS** and we've gone with the pod structure. Each pod for us is a different application that works independent to every other pod and comes from its own subversion repository. I would like for each pod to specify its own routes so that I can just add a new pod and not have to alter the main `router.js`. Is this at all possible in **EmberJS**?

Comment: Why don't you split your application into small applications? Expose common parts as addons and reuse them at small applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of features in the works to allow this to happen for you.  Not all of them are ready yet.

Ember Engines is what you want.  It is (Experimentally) available as an addon, which should at least get you close to what you want, but keep in mind it is still experimental.:

https://github.com/dgeb/ember-engines

RFC: https://github.com/emberjs/rfcs/blob/master/text/0010-engines.md

There is also an RFC for a new pod structure which will allow Addons and Engines to define their own routes.js

RFC: https://github.com/dgeb/rfcs/blob/module-unification/text/0000-module-unification.md

None of these are 100% ready as of yet, but keep an eye on them.